# Fetch all the data from HTML table with Regex using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, regex, filter

I have a code which should filter data from HTML table based on conditions . i have around 200 records in my table and many of them is common name

so for example , i have a row with value "GowriLakshmi" , so if i search "%Laksh%" it should display all the name with Laksh in between there names .

So currently i tried but am not getting it . it is not throwing me any error . but am not able to find logic for that . So can anyone help me on this .

attaching code :

```js
const table = $('#tblfiles');

$('#tblfiles').dataTable({
  'search': {
    'smart': false,
    'regex': true
  }
});

$('.dataTables_filter input').unbind().bind('keyup', function() {
  const searchTerm =  this.value.toLowerCase().replace(/,/g, '|').replace('%', '.*');
        var LastItem = ''
  var lastChar = searchTerm[searchTerm.length -1];
    if(lastChar == '|'){
        LastItem = (searchTerm.substring(0,searchTerm.length - 1));
  }
  //Regex to be used : -- > \wst\w* 

  const regex = '\\b(' + searchTerm + ')\\b';
  table.DataTable().rows().search(regex, true, false).draw();
});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 12px !important;
  padding: 2em;
}

.dataTables_length {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chance/1.1.7/chance.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<div id="nam"></div>
<br>

<table id="tblfiles" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>111</td>
      <td>GowriLakshmi</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>112</td>
      <td>Lakshmi</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>113</td>
      <td>Paaru</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>114</td>
      <td>michael</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>115</td>
      <td>Mohammed</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1132</td>
      <td>Naziya</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1131</td>
      <td>Nazriya</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1131</td>
      <td>LakshKarthyayini</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So i know which regex to be used for that , but when i include that regex it is not working as expected . Am new to this web development , and i am still learning . So can someone of you help .

Answer (score 0):

To filter the record with value you can pass the your searchTerm directly to search function of datatable.

Try this :

```
const table = $('#tblfiles');

$('#tblfiles').dataTable({
  'search': {
    'smart': false,
    'regex': true
  }
});

$('.dataTables_filter input').unbind().bind('keyup', function() {

  const searchTerm =  this.value.toLowerCase();  

  table.DataTable().rows().search(searchTerm).draw();
});
```

For your reference :  https://jsfiddle.net/sha4d6cm/

Comment: i also want comma separated one , like for example i have 200 data's in table . so i want to filter multiple data at same time using comma . it should filter the data even if i give comma

Comment: for multiple data search you change search term and regex to this : const searchTerm =  this.value.toLowerCase().replace(/,/g, '|');
  const regex =  '^.*' + searchTerm + '\.*$';

Comment: but when i give comma , at end without succeeding it with anything , it retrieved me entire table data

Comment: you can avoid that case by adding a regex which will remove comma if there is no character after it. try this:  searchTerm.replace(/,\s*$/, "")  https://jsfiddle.net/he4comxb/